# PageDown through ScriptEngine incorrectly parsing Markdown

Tags: javascript, java, markdown, scriptengine, pagedown

I am trying to use [PageDown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) on the client side as an editor, and on the server side to then parse that Markdown to HTML.

It seems to work fine on the client side, but on the server side, tickmarks are only "codifying" the character that follows, not the word that it wraps. So if I do this:

`` test `test` test ``

I expect this, and this is indeed what I get on the client side:

`test <code>test</code> test`

But on the server side, I end up getting this instead:

`test <code>t</code>est<code> </code>test`

I've created a file called `pageDown.js`, which is simply [`Markdown.Converter.js`](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/Markdown.Converter.js) and [`Markdown.Sanitizer.js`](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/Markdown.Sanitizer.js) combined into a single file, with this function added:

```
function getSanitizedHtml(pagedown){
    var converter =  new Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
    return converter.makeHtml(pagedown);
}
```

On the client side, I can use this file like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="pageDown.js"></script>
<script>
function convert(){

    var html = getSanitizedHtml("test `test` test");

    console.log(html);

    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = html;
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="convert()">
<p id="content"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

That correctly displays: `<p>test <code>test</code> test</p>`

On the (Java) server side, I use this same exact file, through Java's `ScriptEngineManager` and `Invocable`:

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

public class PageDownTest{

    public static void main(String... args){

        try{
            ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
            engine.eval(new InputStreamReader(PageDownTest.class.getResourceAsStream("pageDown.js")));
            Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
            String s = String.valueOf(inv.invokeFunction("getSanitizedHtml", "test `test` test"));
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

That program prints out this: `<p>test <code>t</code>est<code></code>test</p>`

I see similar problems with other markdown: `test **test** test` simply ignores the `**` part. However, `##test` correctly returns as `<h2>test</h2>`.

This all works fine if I go to the JavaScript directly through HTML, but not when I go through Java. What's going on here? Should I be handling Markdown on the server differently?

Comment: The project wiki mentions using Node.JS on the server, that's your last resort.

Comment: Not sure why this question has a bounty. The only answer clearly states that the issue is a bug in the library being used. The bug should be reported upstream to the maintainers of that library. There is not anything else we can do here to help.

Comment: @Waylan The bounty was added **before** the answer. The only reason the answer was posted was because I added the bounty. That's how bounties work.

Comment: Opps, sorry, I missed the timing. I understand how they work just missed which happened first. Ignore the noise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to reduce the problem to the following code:

```
function getSanitizedHtml(text)
{
    return text.replace(/(a)(?!b)\1/gm, 'c');
}
```

When called in the browser as

```
getSanitizedHtml('aa');
```

it returns:

```
c
```

When called from the Nashorn engine as

```
String s = String.valueOf(inv.invokeFunction("getSanitizedHtml", "aa"));
```

it returns:

```
cc
```

To me, this looks like the backreference `\1`, which should point to `(a)`, instead points to `(?!b)`, whose captured content is zero-length and thus matches anything.

The equivalent code in Java:

```
System.out.println(("aa").replaceAll("(a)(?!b)\\1", "c"));
```

returns the correct result though:

```
c
```

## Conclusion

I'm pretty sure this is a bug in the Nashorn engine.
I filed a bug report and will post its ID here, if it goes public.

As for your problem, I think your only option is to switch to a different JavaScript environment, at least temporarily.

## Minimal, runnable examples

JS in browser:

```js
function x(s){return s.replace(/(a)(?!b)\1/gm, 'c');}
document.write(x('aa'));
```

JS in Nashorn engine:

**[ [Ideone](https://ideone.com/elU4iM) ]**

Pure Java:

**[ [Ideone](https://ideone.com/62pe45) ]**

## Possible fix

As already pointed out, your only option (at this point) is to switch to another JavaScript environment.
There are many of those available, and Wikipedia has [a comparison page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_server-side_JavaScript_solutions). For this example, I've chosen [io.js](https://iojs.org/en/) (I trust you'll manage to install it on your own).

If you want to use your pageDown.js file, you'll first need to comment out the `exports` checks and use the plain old variables, like this:

```
/*if (typeof exports === "object" && typeof require === "function") // we're in a CommonJS (e.g. Node.js) module
    Markdown = exports;
else*/
    Markdown = {};
```

and

```
/*if (typeof exports === "object" && typeof require === "function") { // we're in a CommonJS (e.g. Node.js) module
    output = exports;
    Converter = require("./Markdown.Converter").Converter;
} else {*/
    output = Markdown;
    Converter = output.Converter;
//}
```

(Note that I also changed `output = window.Markdown;` to `output = Markdown;` - you must have done the same (Nashorn would have given you an error otherwise), but just forgot to mention that in your question.)

Alternatively, you could of course use the exports system and separate files, but I have no experience with that, so I'll do it this way.

Now, io.js accepts JavaScript code from stdin, and you can write to stdout via `process.stdout.write()`, so we can do the following (on the command line):

```
{ cat pageDown.js; echo 'process.stdout.write(getSanitizedHtml("test `test` test"));'; } | iojs;
```

And we get the following back:

```
<p>test <code>test</code> test</p>
```

If you need to do that from Java, you can do it like this:

```
import java.io.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/to/iojs");
        OutputStream stdin = p.getOutputStream();
        InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
        File file = new File("/path/to/pageDown.js");
        byte[] b = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        for(int read = 0; read < b.length; read += in.read(b, read, b.length - read)); // <-- note the semicolon
        stdin.write(b);
        stdin.write("process.stdout.write(getSanitizedHtml('test `test` test'));".getBytes());
        stdin.close(); // <-- important to close
        p.waitFor();
        b = new byte[stdout.available()];
        stdout.read(b);
        System.out.println(new String(b));
    }
}
```

Note the semicolon directly after the `for` (so it only does `read += in.read(b, read, b.length - read)` every time, and nothing else) and also note that while calling `.close()` on a stream is usually optional, as it will be done automatically when the object goes out of scope, `stdin.close()` has to be called here, or `iojs` will continue to wait for input, and `p.waitFor()` will never return.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What other JavaScript environments can I switch to?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/markdown/markdown.github.com/wiki/Implementations) is a lengthy (albeit incomplete) list of known Markdown implementations. I can't speak to the quality of any of the JavaScript libraries listed there, but perhaps one of them will be useful.